# Не могу понять как реализовать с помощью tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Реализацией визуализацию случайного пути точки. Точка сначала находится в центре экрана. На каждой итерации цикла случайно выбирается направление движения и точка перемещается на определенный шаг вдоль этого направления. Затем интонации повторяются.

1. Запустите симуляцию с разной величиной шага.
2. Задайте точке приоритетное направление движения.
3. Сделайте интерактивную версию, в которой приоритетное направление

У меня получилось реализовать что то подобное с помощью turtle, но сожалению необходимо именно на tkinter

```py
import turtle
import random
import math

turtle.setup(1000, 1000)
turtle.title("Random Walk ")
a = turtle.Turtle()


a.color('red')

tlist = [a]

turtle.speed(0)
turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.hideturtle()
sum = 0
count = 0
for j in range(100):
    for i in range(10000):
        for t in tlist:
            t.seth(random.randrange(0, 360, 90))
            t.fd(10)
        turtle.update()
    for t in tlist:
        sum += math.sqrt(t.xcor() * t.xcor() + t.ycor() * t.ycor()) / 10 * 2 * math.sqrt(
            t.xcor() * t.xcor() + t.ycor() * t.ycor()) / 10 * 2 / 100
        count += 10
    for t in tlist:
        t.clear()
        t.up()
        t.goto(0, 0)
        t.down()
    print(sum / count)
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста что вы попытались сделать.

Comment: а в чём конкретно затруднение ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246872/how-to-combine-tkinter-and-turtle